# Is it possible to load non image page to UIImageView

Tags: javascript, html, ios, svg, uiimageview

I have images stored in remote server and getting those images from server using JSON then load to UIImageView. Now, i have html page with color option using SVG format. I need to load this page page to UIImageView. My url like this server.net/projects/coloroption (this page containing html code). But in my code mmageview accepting only image format. How can i load color changing option to mmageview?

```
 mmageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,150,150)];

     [mmageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

     //  [mmageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[productimg_array objectAtIndex:[sender tag]-1]]]]];

     [mmageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[productimg_array objectAtIndex:[sender tag]-1]] placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {


     }];

    [mmageView setTag:[sender tag]-1];

        [self.view addSubview:mmageView];
```

Comment: It's not very clear what your webpage is returning, SVG or HTML. Sounds like you need a `UIWebView'

Comment: Yes. UIWebView does this but my previous version app having code for load png or jpg format images from server. I need to use this page to UIImageView http://center.net/projects/lite/

Comment: The AFnetworking uiimageview setImageWithURL uses AFImageResponseSerializer by default. This accepts image formats like bmp,jpeg,tiff but not SVG. You either need to do something like subclass AFImageResponseSerializer to handle SVG or change the server to generate and return a jpeg, bmp etc